# Prove or disprove three sentence about $\int_{a}^{b}f(t)\text{d}t$ (convexity)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convex-analysis

> Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ a non-decreasing function. Define $F:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x}f(t)\text{d}t$. In the sentences below, prove or give a counterexample:
>
> (1) The function $F$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$.
>
> (2) Given $x_{0} \in (a,b)$, then $F(x) - F(x_{0}) \geq w(x - x_{0})$, for any $x \in (a,b)$ and $w \in [f(x_{0}^{-}),f(x_{0}^{+})]$.Here, $f(x_{0}^{-})$ $[f(x_{0}^{+})]$ is the left [right] limit of $f$ in $x_{0}$.
>
> (3) $F$ is convex. If $f$ is inscreasing, then $F$ is strictly convex.

(1) Is false. Some functions defined by parts, works.

(3) If (2) is true, can I show that $\frac{F(x) - F(x_{0})}{x - x_{0}}$ is non-decreasing? $F$ be convex seems reasonable.

(2) $F(x) - F(x_{0}) = \int_{x_{0}}^{x}f(t)\text{d}t$ if $x \geq x_{0}$ and $F(x) - F(x_{0}) = -\int_{x_{0}}^{x}f(t)\text{d}t$ if $x \leq x_{0}$. So, probably (2) is true, but I have no idea about how to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\begin{cases} -1 \,\, \text{if} \,\, x\in [-1,0[ \\ 1 \,\, \text{if} \,\, x\in [0,1]  \end{cases}$. 
This should cover problem $(1)$.

$(3)$ is true, just check the definition of convexity (the actual definition, not the sufficient condition with the derivative, as it is not applicable here due to the above counter-example).

Comment: I've been able to show that $F$ is convex, but I didn't get the strict inequality if $f$ is increasing. Basically, I use $f(x) \leq f(y)$ implies $\int f(x) \leq \int f(y)$, but the strict inequality is not necessary true in the integrals, right?

Comment: Isn't it? Think about it again. Assume that you have a(n integrable) function which is strictly positive on an interval. I claim that its integral is also strictly positive, then.

Comment: I guess you messed up the notations, because what you wrote in your comment, strictly speaking, makes no sense formally. Try to fix the notations, and you will see, you have to use what I just suggested.

Comment: I see! I think I got it!

Comment: Great! Item $(2)$ is more technical, but maybe you have some intuition about the problem, and you can think about it.