# Prove or disprove sentence about $\int f$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I post [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2885594/444015) question a few months ago. I solved the items (1) and (3), but I cannot to solve (2). Today I read this question again and I'm curious about solution of (2). Today, I had an idea, but I dont know if it works.

---

**Idea**. A monotone function has only jump discontinuities. So, $f|_{[f(x_{0}^{-}),f(x_{0}^{+})]}$ is continuous, then there is a maximum and minimum. If $w$ is a minimum on $[f(x_{0}^{-}),f(x_{0}^{+})]$, then

$$w \leq f(x) \Longrightarrow w(x-x_{0}) \leq \int_{x_{0}}^{x}f(t)dt = F(x) - F(x_{0})$$

taking, WLOG, $x \geq x_{0}$. But, this works for $f$ on $[f(x_{0}^{-}),f(x_{0}^{+})]$. What about the general case?

Comment: $[f(x_0^+),f(x_0^-)]$ does not necessarily belong to the domain of $f$. You cannot define the restriction of $f$ on that interval.

Comment: @nicomezi I see. Do you have any hint? Or do you know if there is any way to adapt that idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suppose $x>x_0$. Then
$$F(x) - F(x_0) = \int_{x_0}^{x}f(t)dt \geq \inf_{t \in (x_0,x]} f(t) \cdot (x-x_0) = f(x_0^+) \cdot (x-x_0) \geq w \cdot (x-x_0).$$

Now let $x < x_0$. Then
$$F(x) - F(x_0) = \int_{x_0}^{x}f(t)dt  = - \int_{x}^{x_0}f(t)dt = \int_{x}^{x_0}(-f(t))dt \geq \inf_{t \in [x,x_0)} (-f(t)) \cdot (x_0-x)\\
= (- \sup_{t \in [x,x_0)} f(t)) \cdot (x_0-x) = \sup_{t \in [x,x_0)} f(t) \cdot (x-x_0) = f(x_0^-) \cdot (x-x_0) \geq w \cdot (x-x_0).$$